# Not getting remote claims from wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have using **wso2 IS** with another configured identity provider like: google,yahoo.
when i logged form IDP and redirect back to callback URL my application
call **/outh2/token** **API** to fetch **id_token** base on **authorization_code** but the problem is not getting remote claim (IDP custom claim attribute) which i have configured in service provider mapping.I have facing this issues randomly not for all user.

**Success claims Log**:TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-24 07:25:03,300] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.claims.impl.DefaultClaimHandler} -  **Returning claims from claim handler = [middle_name:M,given_name:abc,family_name:xyz,email:abc.xyz@domain.com,]**

**Failure claims Log:**  07:32:19,062] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.claims.impl.DefaultClaimHandler} -  **Returning claims from claim handler = []**

Comment: do you have the above-mentioned custom claim values assigned to that user which is giving failure?

Comment: yes,It's working for same user login and getting failed some time for same user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are facing the issue mentioned in [1]. This issue is fixed in master branch and also the fix is available as wum update for IS-5.4.0 and IS-5.5.0. You can either try the latest milestone of WSO2 Identity Server or get a wum updated pack of IS 5.4.0 or IS 5.5.0.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/issues/1494

Comment: Thanks Nilasini for update, I have been using 5.4.0 version and as per my analysis after enable debug log authentication-framework/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authentication/framework/handler/claims/impl/DefaultClaimHandler.java 
when logInput() method invoke at that remote claims was available but while handleFederatedClaims() invoke remote claims has lost from map logOutput() in this method log.

Comment: I have been try with wso2 IS 5.5.0 but still facing same issues. As per my analysis remote claims miss place from this class method DefaultClaimHandler.java->handleFederatedClaims().

Comment: The fix is only available in the atest milestone of WSO2 Identity Server. You can find the latest milestone in https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases. If you want to try out with 5.4.0 or 5.5.0 then you need to get a wum updated pack. Did you try with wum updated pack?. The above fix is only available via wum update for IS-5.4.0 and 5.5.0.

Comment: I have cloned 5.6.0 latest milestone as per above mentioned link and configured all required setting but while update SP I have facing below error: Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
do you have any help regarding this why this exception happen in 5.6.0.

Comment: Are you getting any exception from the server startup also?. If you give me the full stack trace, I can help you on this because in default 5.6.0-m6 pack with MySQL as the database with JDBC user store there were no issues with updating SP.

Comment: Thanks Nilasini for support, I am getting error "No claim manager setter found for class Application Authentication Framework bundle" while startup application and please find-out full stack log of Wso2 refer issues report link by me: https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/3128. I have attached  startup log as well SP update error log.

Comment: The error "No claim manager setter found for class Application Authentication Framework bundle" may be coming because in user-mgt.xml file the property "initializeNewClaimManager" is missing. The errors while updating SP is coming from mssql. You can track the update through the git issue. For now if you are ok, then you can use mysql or h2 database and check whether your actual problem reported(not getting claims) is solved with IS-5.6.0-m6.

Comment: we have using MSSQL in production it is not possible to migrate Mysql/H2 database.
Getting claims from wso2 is intermittent issues for us not always.
Do you have any work around on this?
Please refer Issues Report by me with full stack strace: https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/3129

Comment: Since this is production, recommended and the best way is to have wso2 wum subscription, so that you can get future bug fixes as well or else wait for the next milestone which will be in one week which will include the issue reported as git issue 3128.

Comment: As a workaround, for now you can fork the https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework and checkout to the specific tag (for IS-5.5.0 you need to check out to 5.11.148) and get the fix from https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/pull/1495/files and apply it manually and build the jar and then replace the jar in the plugins folder with this newly built jar( org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework_5.11.148.jar).

Comment: Unfortunately with 5.4.0 you can't apply this work around for this issue because logic of the fix is different for 5.4.0 because of some API changes.If you want to solve the issue for 5.4.0 then only option is get a wum update