# Unable to delete user from Wso2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am not able to delete user from wso2 (intermediately).
For deleting user i have used **RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub** service in my application.

**WSO2 Stack Trace Log:**

```
 TID: [-1234] [] [2018-05-26 16:30:35,971] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver} -  Error when handling event : POST_DELETE_USER 
    org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error when handling event : POST_DELETE_USER
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:173)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.deleteUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1273)
        at org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.service.UserStoreManagerService.deleteUser(UserStoreManagerService.java:164)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:66)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:147)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:232)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:163)
        ... 62 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager$2.run(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:166)
        ... 64 more
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error when handling event : POST_DELETE_USER
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener.handleEvent(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:619)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener.handleEvent(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:572)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener.doPostDeleteUser(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:298)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.deleteUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1348)
        ... 69 more
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.IdentityEventException: Error while deleting consents for user abc.register@outlook.com
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.consent.mgt.handler.ConsentDeletionUserEventHandler.handleEvent(ConsentDeletionUserEventHandler.java:135)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.services.IdentityEventServiceImpl.handleEvent(IdentityEventServiceImpl.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener.handleEvent(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:604)
        ... 72 more
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.exception.ConsentManagementServerException: Error while searching receipts.
        at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.util.ConsentUtils.handleServerException(ConsentUtils.java:64)
        at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.dao.impl.ReceiptDAOImpl.searchReceipts(ReceiptDAOImpl.java:303)
        at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.ConsentManagerImpl.searchReceipts(ConsentManagerImpl.java:589)
        at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.ConsentManagerImpl.searchReceipts(ConsentManagerImpl.java:562)
        at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.InterceptingConsentManager$21.execute(InterceptingConsentManager.java:546)
        at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.InterceptingConsentManager$21.execute(InterceptingConsentManager.java:542)
        at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.model.ConsentInterceptorTemplate.executeWith(ConsentInterceptorTemplate.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.InterceptingConsentManager.searchReceipts(InterceptingConsentManager.java:542)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.consent.mgt.handler.ConsentDeletionUserEventHandler.handleEvent(ConsentDeletionUserEventHandler.java:121)
        ... 74 more
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.database.utils.jdbc.exceptions.DataAccessException: Error in performing Database query: '%s'SELECT CONSENT_RECEIPT_ID, LANGUAGE, PII_PRINCIPAL_ID, PRINCIPAL_TENANT_ID, STATE, SP_DISPLAY_NAME, SP_DESCRIPTION FROM (SELECT R.CONSENT_RECEIPT_ID, R.LANGUAGE, R.PII_PRINCIPAL_ID, R.PRINCIPAL_TENANT_ID, R.STATE, RS.SP_DISPLAY_NAME, RS.SP_DESCRIPTION, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY R.CONSENT_RECEIPT_ID) AS ROWNUM FROM CM_RECEIPT R INNER JOIN CM_RECEIPT_SP_ASSOC RS ON R.CONSENT_RECEIPT_ID = RS.CONSENT_RECEIPT_ID WHERE PII_PRINCIPAL_ID LIKE ? AND PRINCIPAL_TENANT_ID=? AND SP_NAME LIKE ? AND STATE LIKE ?) AS RES WHERE RES.ROWNUM BETWEEN ? AND ?
        at org.wso2.carbon.database.utils.jdbc.JdbcTemplate.executeQuery(JdbcTemplate.java:168)
        at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.dao.impl.ReceiptDAOImpl.searchWithoutSpTenant(ReceiptDAOImpl.java:382)
        at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.dao.impl.ReceiptDAOImpl.searchReceipts(ReceiptDAOImpl.java:293)
        ... 81 more
    Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'CM_RECEIPT'.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1493)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:390)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:340)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:154)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:283)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.database.utils.jdbc.JdbcTemplate.executeQuery(JdbcTemplate.java:153)
        ... 83 more
```

Can any one tell me why it's happened (intermediate only)?
**WSO2 IS Version: 5.5.0 with patch**
Suggested link for patch (Reason for patch: remote claims not getting issues): [Not getting remote claims from wso2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997900/not-getting-remote-claims-from-wso2/50007950?noredirect=1#comment87192058_50007950)

Comment: when you send the delete request via soap, are you always using the same user for authentication purpose in failure and success scenarios?. Did you check the database connection while you get this error? because according to the stack trace the issue is caused by "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'CM_RECEIPT'". This means you don't have table "CM_RECEIPT" in your database. Since this is intermittent I guess table is there but the connection to the database may be got a loss. Could you please verify that?

Comment: Thanks for continues support. yes,i send this request using soap call.
To create RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub instance and call.
For authentication in success/failure scenario not using same user.
Database connection is up during those time and CM_RECEIPT table is not exist in database may be not created by initialize time of Wso2.
one strange thing when i had checked in wso2 user was deleted successfully with exception.
if user was deleted from wso2 it should not throw any exception because base on delete response further work flow continue in my application.

Comment: Did you do any database migration? The table CM_RECEIPT is created during the first startup if you start the identity server with "-Dsetup"?. If the tables were created manually and if you have missed that then you can create this tables using the script in <IS_HOME>/dbscripts/consent/mssql.sql. Did you mean that even though you are getting the above exception, you could able to delete the user?.

Comment: Thank you Nilasini for your inputs and support.
CM_RECEIPT table not created at our end, as we had started wso2IS service first time without '-Dsetup' argument.
That's why table was missed from database.
I had executed the script suggested by you, it has created CM_RECEIPT table and issue is resolved now. Thanks again :-)